# Swing UIManager default system look and feel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I'm writing a Java application and I'm giving it a custom look and feel using the `UIManager` of Swing. There's a method named `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` that returns the default look and feel of a system. I would like to know what look and feel it returns as default, when no system look and feel was detected, is it the Metal look and feel of Java itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the docs for the function:
[`UIManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html):

> Returns the name of the LookAndFeel class that implements the native
>   system look and feel if there is one, otherwise the name of the
>   default cross platform LookAndFeel class. This value can be overriden
>   by setting the `swing.systemlaf` system property.

See also `getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()` in the same doc page.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I've googled for it, I always do but somehow I was not able to find the javadocs :(